# Different spacing for anchor and heading tags on vertical axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to layout a footer for my site using Flexbox. There are two columns, each with the same number of items, except for one column is being populated by text in `<h4>` tags and other links in `<a>` tags. They are spaced differently on the vertical axis and I can't work out why. I have added some background colours for clarity.

[image]

What am I missing?

```css
.footer {
  font-family: 'nexa_light', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #003152;
  color: white;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.foot-section {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.foot-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.foot-section a {
  /*links*/
  color: white;
}

.footer-container>h5 {
  /*Copyright*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .foot-section h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .foot-section a,
  .foot-section h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footer">
  <div class="footer-container row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Company</strong></h2>
        <h4>London, UK</h4>
        <h4>Logo by X</h4>
        <h4>Something else</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Quick Links</strong></h2>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <a href="#">News & Reviews</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Contact</strong></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h5>Copyright © X Ltd 2020, All Rights Reserved. |</h5><a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Browsers automatically apply bottom margin to heading tags, but not anchor tags. Also, that's not an appropriate use of `<h4>` tags, as those lines are not headings for sections of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading elements (such as an `h4`) tend to have top and bottom margins set in [browser default style sheets](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/sample.html).

These margins aren't applied to anchor elements (`a`).

Here are the styles applied to `h4` elements in Chrome:

[image]

You can see that the top and bottom margins are 1.33em.

- "block-start" is the top in horizontal writing mode.
- "inline-start" is the side where text begins. It's the left side in LTR.
- "-end" refers to the opposite side.
- source: [§ 6.2. Flow-relative Directions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#logical-directions)

You just need to override the defaults. Add this to your code: `h4 { margin: 0; }`.

```css
  /* NEW */

.foot-section h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  font-family: 'nexa_light', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #003152;
  color: white;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.foot-section {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.foot-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.foot-section a {
  /*links*/
  color: white;
}

.footer-container>h5 {
  /*Copyright*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .foot-section h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .foot-section a,
  .foot-section h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footer">
  <div class="footer-container row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Company</strong></h2>
        <h4>London, UK</h4>
        <h4>Logo by X</h4>
        <h4>Something else</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Quick Links</strong></h2>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <a href="#">News & Reviews</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 foot-section">
      <div class="foot-content">
        <h2><strong>Contact</strong></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h5>Copyright © X Ltd 2020, All Rights Reserved. |</h5><a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```